# show div onclick, add class to the div and get the similar process for the other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of div i wanted to add `.active` class to the div `.verified-account` when clicking `.title-box.has-value` it should also add class to `.screen-answer`.

So if the next div is clicked, the previous clicked and active div needs to get his class removed (so deactive) and his row beneath hidden. The next selected div needs to get the same process as the previous.

```
<div class="screen-start">
<div class="screenbox">
<div class="btn-screen box-start">
<div class="title-box has-value blue-bg">YES</div>
<div class="verified-account"></div>
</div>
<div class="btn-screen box-start">
<div class="title-box has-value green-bg">AMAZING!!!</div>
<div class="verified-account"></div>
</div>
<div class="btn-screen box-start">
<div class="title-box has-value green-bg">MAYBE YES.</div>
<div class="verified-account"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="screen-answerbox">
<div class="screen-answer blue">This was a active
</div>
<div class="screen-answer green">This was a active
</div>
<div class="screen-answer green">This was a active
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var selector = '.title-box.has-value';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
$(selector).closest('.btn-review').find('.icons8-verified-account').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('.btn-review').find('.icons8-verified-account').addClass('active');
$(selector).parents('.rating-start').find('.range-answer').removeClass('active');
$(this).parents('.rating-start').find('.range-answer').addClass('active');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
$('.verified-account').removeClass("active");
$(this).next('.verified-account').addClass("active");
```

The first line removed `.active` from all elements with the class `verified-account`;

The second line adds the class `active` to the `verified-account` element related to the click element.

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var selector = '.title-box.has-value';

  $(selector).on('click', function() {
    var inx = $(selector).index(this);
    $(selector).closest('.btn-review').find('.icons8-verified-account').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.btn-review').find('.icons8-verified-account').addClass('active');
    $(selector).parents('.rating-start').find('.range-answer').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.rating-start').find('.range-answer').addClass('active');
    $('.verified-account').removeClass("active");
    $(this).next('.verified-account').addClass("active");
    $('.screen-answer').removeClass("active");
    $('.screen-answer').eq(inx).addClass("active")
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="screen-start">
  <div class="screenbox">
    <div class="btn-screen box-start">
      <div class="title-box has-value blue-bg">YES</div>
      <div class="verified-account">Verify</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-screen box-start">
      <div class="title-box has-value green-bg">AMAZING!!!</div>
      <div class="verified-account">Verify</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-screen box-start">
      <div class="title-box has-value green-bg">MAYBE YES.</div>
      <div class="verified-account">Verify</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="screen-answerbox">
    <div class="screen-answer blue">This was a active
    </div>
    <div class="screen-answer green">This was a active
    </div>
    <div class="screen-answer green">This was a active
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please read the question again, if you test my code it add class to verified-account perfectly, however it add active class to all screen-answer div, it should only add to first one and vice versa.

Comment: @WaleedAfridi Try my demo now, got confused since the 4 lines in your click event did nothing related to your html